# Missing ; before statement in Google Script

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, google-apps-script, wolframalpha

It says I have a Missing ; before statement on the "var api =..." line.
I'm not sure what else it is I need to do. 
If you need to see the rest of the script, please let me know. I will gladly submit everything else.

```
function askWolframAlpha_(q, app) {

try {

var api = "http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?podindex=2&format=plaintext&appid=" + 67ULAK-L9R928PL76 + "&input=" + encodeURIComponent(q);
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(api, {
  muteHttpException: true
});

// Parse the XML response
if (response.getResponseCode() == 200) {
  var document = XmlService.parse(response.getContentText());
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  if (root.getAttribute("success").getValue() === "true") {
    return root.getChild("pod").getChild("subpod").getChild("plaintext").getText();
  }
}
} catch (f) {}
return false;
}
```

Comment: `67ULAK-L9R928PL76` is not a valid string or identifier. You probably want to remove the quotes and `+`s surrounding that so it's in the string itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the 67ULAK-L9R928PL76 in the following line:

```
var api = "http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?podindex=2&format=plaintext&appid=" + 67ULAK-L9R928PL76 + "&input=" + encodeURIComponent(q);
```

Change to:

```
var api = "http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?podindex=2&format=plaintext&appid=67ULAK-L9R928PL76&input=" + encodeURIComponent(q);
```

or at least to:

```
var api = "http://api.wolframalpha.com/v2/query?podindex=2&format=plaintext&appid=" + "67ULAK-L9R928PL76" + "&input=" + encodeURIComponent(q);
```